# click in anywhere changed page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I want to understand how the transition to another page of the site is performed by clicking on this site https://weareundefined.be/

understendd that this library is used https://revealjs.com/

I see that this revealjs.com library works as a slider, but it flips the page when the buttons are clicked, I could somehow add a code to it so that the page flips when I click anywhere
p.s I just started learning js

Maybe someone will tell me something

Comment: Questions like "how do they do it" are simply far too broad for Stack Overflow as outlined in the [help]

Comment: 1) you don't need the revealjs.com lib to change the page on a click. 2) they are not going to a new page. Just a different place on the same page. 3) what exactly do you want to do and show some code of what you've tried

Comment: @DCR can you describe in more detail how to do it?
if not difficult

Comment: @DCR I want the filling of the page to change in one click anywhere as on this site https://weareundefined.be/

Comment: 1) create all the different sections with each section having a unique id. 2) hide all the section with css of display:none. 3) add a click eventlistener on body 4) in the click function toggle display for the what's seen i.e set the current section to display:none and set the next section to display:block

Comment: @DCR i can buy you it

Comment: @DCR ty for info

Comment: no problem.  You will find in general the more effort you put into your questions, the more work you show, the faster and more complete answers you will get.  Always try to include a snippet that shows the problem you are having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("click",myClick)
var divs= document.getElementsByClassName('section')
for(let i = 0;i<divs.length;i++){
   divs[i].style.display='none'
}
divs[0].style.display='block'
var colors=['green','red','blue']


function myClick(){
   var currentId;
   for(let i = 0;i<divs.length;i++){   
   
      if(divs[i].style.display == 'block'){
         currentId = i;
         divs[i].style.display='none'
      }    
   }
   divs[(currentId + 1) % divs.length].style.display='block';
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor=colors[(currentId + 1) % divs.length];

}
```

```html
<div id='s1' class ='section'>section 1</div>
<div id='s2' class ='section'>section 2</div>
<div id='s3' class ='section'>section 3</div>
```